# Does the setting of socket options require namespace switching?

Tags: sockets, namespaces

In Linux, suppose a socket is created by switching to a namespace "red" from the "default" namespace. (After the socket creation, the namespace is switched back to the "default" namespace).

To set socket options on the created socket using "setsockopt" do we need to switch the namespace again ?

I have not found any references about how to set these socket options in case of different namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

No. Linux sockets are permanently attached to the namespace where they were created. Anything you do to that socket will affect it in the namespace where it was created, even if the current namespace is different.